# Node.js Live Search with Dropdown Results

Tags: html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a live-search function which will display results as the user types. I currently have the backend working properly, and am trying to figure out the frontend rendering.

I currently have a search bar embedded into a sidebar where I would like to display the results as a dropdown underneath the search bar.

**Seach Bar**

```
<form class="form-inline-search" onsubmit="return getSearchResults();">
    <div class="form-group sidebar-search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="searchInput" aria-label="Search" class="form-control search" placeholder="Search for..." type="text" onkeypress="liveSearch()">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="searchButton" aria-label="searchButton" class="btn btn-default search" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </span>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-toggle" id="togLiveResults" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="liveResults" aria-labelledby="liveResults"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am able to append the results from the database as list options in my function, however I am unable to get the dropdown **to appear** with what I have. In other words, the dropdown isn't rendering on the page although it is populated.

**Javascript**

```
...
success: function(result) {
    $("#liveResults").empty();

    var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        options += "<li>" + result[i].name + "</li>";
    }
    $("#liveResults").append(options);

    if ($('#liveResults').is(":hidden")) {
        $('#togLiveResults').dropdown('toggle');
    }
},
...
```

What is the reason that I am unable to make the dropdown with results visible, is there more to this that I am missing?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wdnhfg3/1/) for an example.

**Solved**
I had an incorrect nesting for some DOM objects. Changing the dropdown to the following corrected my issue:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle" id="togLiveResults" data-toggle="dropdown"></div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="liveResults" aria-labelledby="liveResults"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you do a `console.log(result)`, does the console display the items?  You may need to use `result.data` to access them.

Comment: @MattB Yep, if I `console.log(result)` I am able to see the entire returned array and all items, those are parsing correctly into the list items needed such as `<li>Javascript</li>`

Comment: Can you create a code snippet that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: @shaochuancs I added a JSFiddle, however my expected output is given there. For some reason, it doesn't want to work in my application. Could it be CSS related that it isn't displaying in that case?

Comment: In your application, is there any error printed in console? If you inspect the page elements, does the `options` DOM elements appear?

Comment: None being thrown. Console is clean, and the `<li>` options all appear in the DOM.

Comment: @shaochuancs Solved, check original question. Having you make me double check my formatting made me realize I had an incorrect nesting for my DOM objects. Thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome :)